# print out pre-design certificate after taking input in php

Tags: php, html

I have a question and maybe there is a better method of doing it beside php but i am throwing the idea out there... let me know your expert advice.

1. I will have a pre designed certificate i will create in PHP and design in HTML.
2. User will be directed to a page to enter the name to print on the certificate.
3. the end result will be sized to 8 1/2" by 11" ready to print.

Image which shows what I am requesting: [Example of Design](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/predesign.png/)

What is the best way to approach this? or is there something thats pre made and can be customized for my request?

Comment: If you need exact dimension printing you might be better off creating a pdf of the certificate server side.  If php is you language take a look at TCPDF.  If HTML is acceptable,  then you could do this without php,  just a html page and a little bit of javascript to pull the name from the query and place it in the page.  If you use HTML be sure to provide an @print  stylesheet,

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback. But what if i have the web server online and the user can visit a link and then produce the certificate? TCPDF seems like its local server only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example in Javascript.

**HTML**:

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
Enter Name:
<input id="who" type="text" />
<input id="submit" type="button" class="btn" value="Submit" />
<div id="certificate" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
    <h1>Certificate of Merit</h1>
    <h3>Presented To:</h3>
    <h4 id="name"></h4>
    <hr />
    <h2>Congratz</h2>
</div>​
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#name').html($('#who').val());
    $('#certificate').fadeIn();
});​
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/6SWVV/1/

Comment: Great example but I am trying to avoid Javascript only for the fact that it can be disabled and the function would have no effect.

Comment: And let's say I do complete using JavaScript, How do print it so it fits exactly on 8 1/2 by 11 paper? Thanks